# How can I determine the probability density function

Tags: probability, statistics

Determine the probability density function and the probability mass function for Y in the following case :
$Y=X^5$

$f_X(x)=5040 \cdot x^3(1-x)^5 \cdot \mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}$

$F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P(X^5 \leq y) = P(X \leq \sqrt{y^5}) = F_X(\sqrt{y^5}) = \int_0^{\sqrt{y^5}} 504t^3(1-t)^5 \, dt = -56t^9+315t^8-720t^7+840t^6-504t^5+126t^4 |_{0,1} = -\sqrt{y}\left(56y^{22}+720y^{17}+504y^{12}\right)+315y^{20}+840y^{15}+126y^{10}$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149252/discussion-on-question-by-student-how-can-i-determine-the-probability-density-f); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.